# Tap action for new complications of watchOS 9

Tags: swiftui, watchkit, apple-watch-complication, nsuseractivity, watchos-9

In earlier watchOS versions (ver>9) we can use **complication descriptor** to add complications and metadata like userActivity for handle tap action in the watch app delegate (according to [AppleDocs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/life_cycles/handling_user_activity)):

> If you create a complication descriptor using the init(identifier:displayName:supportedFamilies:userActivity:) initializer to pass in an NSUserActivity object, when the user taps the corresponding complication, the system activates your app and passes the activity object to your onContinueUserActivity(_:perform:) modifiers.

But this "**CLKComplicationDescriptor(identifier:displayName:supportedFamilies:userActivity:)**" is using ClockKit and is deprecated now. I can't find any replacement for handling the tap event on new complications.
I'm using watchOS 9 with Swift-UI. I want to do an action in my watch app when the user taps on my **.accessoryCorner** complication. I'm handling this behavior in my iOS app and widgets using .widgetURL(myUrl) and handling it in my SceneDelegate, but it does not work in the watch.

Answer (score 0):

```
func handle(_ userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
    debugPrint("userActivity: \(userActivity.activityType)")
    guard let identifier = (userActivity.interaction?.intent as? ConfigurationIntent)?.style, let type = ComplicationType(rawValue: identifier) else {
        return
    }
    debugPrint("identifier: \(identifier)")
}
```

if you use intent in widgetkit, use can identifier the style from custom intent(ConfigurationIntent), then you can check out which widget is clicked

Comment: userActivity.interaction?.intent always nil , Any idea?

Comment: @Haozes Have you implemented the recommendations method in widgetkit and return a custom intent（ConfigurationIntent） in this method ？

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.widgetURL` modifier in your action widget. When tapped, this will launch your watch app and the `onOpenURL()` method receives the url included in the `.widgetURL`